# Write a program to compute for the total amount to be paid by the customer in purchasing items. List is given with prices

Tags: python, php, items

"Write a program to compute for the total amount to be paid by the customer in purchasing items. The program should display a list of five (5) items with their corresponding prices. The user selects items from the list and inputs the item number to be purchased (based on the list) and the quantity for each item to be purchased. This action will be repeated until the user does not select anymore items. The program will display the total amount to be paid by the customer."

This is the type of program I need to make and below is the code that I have made but it stops when I pick the second item, I don't know why it does that.

```
Apple=40.00
Banana=30.00
Fish=100.00
Bread=45.00
Milk=20.00
price=0.00

print("Apple: Php 40.00")
print("Banana: Php 30.00")
print("Fish: Php 100.00")
print("Bread: Php 45.00")
print("Milk: Php 20.00")

while True:
    choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
    if choice == 'Apple':
        choice=input('Would you like to pick another order? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
        else:
            for cost in price:
                sum += cost
                break
                print("Total cost: Php",sum)
                print(" ")
    elif choice == 'Banana':
        choice=input('Would you like to pick another order? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
        else:
            for cost in price:
                sum += cost
                break
                print("Total cost: Php",sum)
                print(" ")
    elif choice == 'Fish':
        choice=input('Would you like to pick another order? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
        else:
            for cost in price:
                sum += cost
                break
                print("Total cost: Php",sum)
                print(" ")
    elif choice == 'Bread':
        choice=input('Would you like to pick another order? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
        else:
            for cost in price:
                sum += cost
                break
                print("Total cost: Php",sum)
                print(" ")
    elif choice == 'Milk':
        choice=input('Would you like to pick another order? y/n\n')
        if choice == 'y':
            choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
        else:
            for cost in price:
                sum += cost
                break
                print("Total cost: Php",sum)
                print(" ")
    else: 
        print("Error!")
    break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   You have a ```break``` after the ```else:``` part.  I believe that's supposed to be in the ```else:``` condition, no?

Answer (score 2):

The reason would be that you break right at the end of your while loop. That should be in your else when you check if a user inputted something incorrectly. Additionally, I would like to share your code simplified. I might have left one or two things out but this is the basic idea using dictionaries.

```
#create our dictionary, shopping items as keys and price of items as values
shoppingDict = {"Apple":40.00,"Banana":30.00,"Fish":100.00,"Bread":45.00,"Milk":20.00}
#iterate through the dictionaries items printing them out in a certain format
for k,v in shoppingDict.items():print(f'{k}: Php {v}')
while True:
    #prompt user to enter an item
    choice=input('\nChoose an item: Apple, Banana, Fish, Bread, Milk\n')
    #check if that item is found in the dictionary
    #if so add the key's value(price) to price
    try:price += shoppingDict.get(choice)
    #if the user does not enter a valid item, we will print error
    except KeyError:print('Error')
    #ask them if they want to play again
    if input('Would you like to go again? y/n') == 'n':
        print(f'Total Cost: {price}')
        break
```

Look [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/) for more about dictionaries

Comment: I was going to provide a similar answer and you beat me to it. +1 Reviewing the original poster’s code, it may be best to elaborate how this code is simplified compared to the way they choose to attempt it.

Comment: Updated my code with some more information on my simplified version @Superspork

Comment: Wait i did try it @BuddyBob but then it says price is not defined.